# Laravel 5 register services providers dynamically

Tags: laravel-5

I saw a lot of providers are loaded in Laravel framework even I don't need to use them right away, so I want to register them whenever I want inside controller.

For example, in my `config/app.php` I comment line which load `ValidationServiceProvider` because in my `home.blade.php` doesn't need validation services, and here is my `app.php`

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    //Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    ...... other services
];
```

But in `LoginController.php` I need that services, how can I load it again to use validation services only in login page?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is for performance purposes, then Laravel offers a nifty way to do that out of the box. Take a look at the [Deferred Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#deferred-providers) section.

Laravel itself loads a lot of providers using deferred providers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read this topic since I faced Laravel performance, but you know, those "big words" is hard to understand with me. I have been checking very single Laravel's services provider and I see they all have deferred configuration. However I don't know why in my debugbar still have over 400 files being loaded, what these file loading for? https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4197/34474241110_777d5de464_o.png

Comment: That is files loaded, a large amount of which is probably your autoloading. Just because a service provider is deferred it doesn't mean the file isn't loaded, it just means the service provider is not registered or booted until it is needed.